# Rhino Mocks - Do we really need stubs?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, rhino-mocks

If it's possible to change mock behaviour in Rhino Mocks using mock.Stub().Return(), why do we need Stubs anyway?

What do we lose by always using MockRepository.GenerateMock()?

One big benefit of using Mocks instead of Stubs is that we will be able to reuse the same instance among all the tests keeping them cleaner and straightforward.

The moq framework works in a similar way... we don't have different objects for mocks and stubs.

(please, don't answer with a link to Fowler's "Mocks aren't stubs" article)

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that Rhino is no longer developed<sup>1</sup>. Newer frameworks drop this mock-stub difference altogether and introduce single term for their *test doubles*:

- [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/): *mock*
- [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy): *fake*
- [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/): *substitute*

Evolution of mocking frameworks seems to push towards *"one general purpose entity"*, instead of having separate different ones depending on test case context.

To learn more on how that separation (mock, stub, fake) originated and what purposes it served, I suggest reading [Mark Seemann's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann) article about [continuum of test doubles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163358.aspx):

> At the one extreme you'll find dummies with absolutely no implementation, and at the other end are full production implementations. Dummies and production implementations are both well-defined, but stubs, spies, and fakes are more difficult to pin down: when does a test spy become a fake? In addition, mocks inhabit a rather large interval in the continuum, since they can be quite complex in some instances but very simple in others.

---

It might seem that Rhino doesn't distinguish between mock and stub, but there are subtle differences. For example, consider stubbing property getter:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IService>();
mock.Stub(m => m.Property).Return(42);
```

This is how you have to do it when object is mock. Stub on the other hand, introduces *property semantics*, which trivialize entire thing:

```
var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IService>();
stub.Property = 42;
```

Even though that's the only one that's coming to my mind at this moment, there might be some more. But still, those are just minor nuances.

<sub>1: As of **05/19/2013**, this may no longer hold true: [Rhino Mocks new home](http://meisinger2.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/rhino-mocks-new-home/)</sub>

Comment: I used moq in some projects and I loved! But right now I'm working on a project that uses Rhino... so, I'm trying to understand why can't we just forget the Stubs and use Mock's for both purposes with this framework just like we do with moq.

Comment: BTW, tks for sharing the article... I'll take a look!

Comment: @MarceloOliveira: I'm quite sure if Rhino was developed, we wouldn't have two separate types. Overall you're right, there's not a lot differences between stub and mock. However, **there are** some (minor though). See my updated answer for example.

Comment: Great catch, but this is valid only if you are stubbing a property with a setter using an Interface. If you're stubbing a property with a private setter using a stub in Rhino you will fail. For some magical reason (or bug), the only possible way to stub properties with private setters is using a Mock (!!!).

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty clear answer [in the documentation](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#WhatisthedifferencebetweenGenerateStubandGenerateMock):

> A mock is an object that we can set expectations on, and which will
>   verify that the expected actions have indeed occurred. A stub is an
>   object that you use in order to pass to the code under test. You can
>   setup expectations on it, so it would act in certain ways, but those
>   expectations will never be verified. A stub's properties will
>   automatically behave like normal properties, and you can't set
>   expectations on them.
>
> If you want to verify the behavior of the code under test, you will
>   use a mock with the appropriate expectation, and verify that. If you
>   want just to pass a value that may need to act in a certain way, but
>   isn't the focus of this test, you will use a stub.
>
> IMPORTANT: A stub will never cause a test to fail.

Comment: This is the concept of stub versus mock, but as I said in the question, YOU CAN use a mock as a stub with Rhino. So, back to my question, what's the benefit of having two separate objects? What do we lose by always using MockRepository.GenerateMock()?

Comment: Yes, you *can* use a mock as a stub.  However, as stated above, if you don't ever want your mock to affect the test result, then use a stub.

Comment: Can you explain why? What about showing some code to prove your argument?